# There isn't a sequence converging pointwise to this function.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to solve this question:

> Show that there isn't a sequence of continuous functions $f_n:[0,1]\to
>  \mathbb R$ converges pointwise to the function $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$
>   such that $f(x)=0$ for $x$ rational and $f(x)=1$, for $x$ irrational.

Of course there isn't a sequence $f_n:[0,1]\to
 \mathbb R$ converges uniformly to the function $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ because $f$ is discontinuous, but when the convergence is pointwise?

I need help here

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See my paper, First-class functions, American Mathematical Monthly, 
Volume 98, Issue 3, March 1991, 
Pages 237-240 .

See also the variant on this question at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34371/on-the-existence-of-a-sequence-of-positive-continuous-functions) where the functions are supposed to go to infinity at the rationals, and then take reciprocals.

Comment: I would like something easier

Comment: Wouldn't we all. Do you have some reason to believe there is something easier?

Comment: yes, this question is one of the list to prepare to the exam of real analysis in $\mathbb R$, by the way it's the only question I couldn't solve.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that this is the case. Then
$$
f^{-1}(1) = \cup_{l=1}^\infty(\cup_{m=1}^\infty(\cap_{n=m}^\infty f_n^{-1}([1-\frac{1}{2^l}, 1+\frac{1}{2^l}]))).
$$
Note that this is a countable union of closed sets, since each $f_n$ is continuous (i.e. an $F_\sigma$ set).

On the other hand, we know that $f_n^{-1}(1) = \mathbb{Q}^c\cap[0,1]$, and so cannot be an $F_\sigma$ set by the Baire Category Theorem.

Edit: After thinking about it a little bit more, I realized that easiest thing to say here is that for a sequence of continuous functions, the set of discontinuities will be meagre, which is clearly not the case here. :)

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space#Properties

Comment: I would like to see your solution anyway

Comment: I tried to fix it, hope this works!

Comment: I don't know what a maigre set is, thank you for your your answer

Comment: I think the union over $l$ in your display should be an intersection, and this breaks your argument.